# Multiple back stacks using navigation component - How to always go to start destination for specific bottom navigation tab?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I'm working on implementing a back stack for each tab of a `BottomNavigationView`. The architecture-component-samples GitHub repo has an example with an extension function called [`setupWithNavController`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/26a7703a3ee3ecc298ce9f28ea93ecccdad665be/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) that provides this functionality. **I'm trying to modify the extension function so a specific bottom nav tab always takes you to the start destination of the associated nav graph.** What is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried popping the back stack of the nav controller to its start destination in the `onNavigationItemSelectedListener`, but this results in the user seeing the back navigation happening, which I don't want.

e.g. after the fragment transaction in the `setupWithNavController` extension function:

```
if(selectedFragment.navController.graph.id == R.id.some_nav_graph){
  fragmentManager.executePendindTransactions()
  selectedFragment.navController.popBackStack(selectedFragment.navController.graph.startDestination, false)
}
```

I've also tried popping the back stack before it's associated nav host is shown, but the `FragmentNavigator` doesn't allow this and results in "Ignoring popBackStack() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just remove then re-add the `NavHostFragment` of the associated nav graph, which results in the back stack of the nav controller being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved in the latest navigation component build 2.4.0-alpha01 but there is a big when using Safe Args in it so until you are not using safe args its perfectly fine